# How much is a Cornucopian ducat in modern currency?

Tags: the-ickabog

In the Ickabog, the ducat is their unit of currency. This is, according to [lexico.com](https://www.lexico.com/definition/ducat):

> a gold coin formerly current in most European countries.

**What's the current conversion rate into USD of Cornucopian ducats?**

According to Wikipedia, ducats of yore contained roughly 3.5 grams of gold, which in today's rate would be approximately $193 at the current rate of $1726.60 per troy ounce.

However, we don't know the weight of the coins in the Ickabog, nor the purity.

---

Here is a list of some of the transactions and mentions of gold/taxes within the text for comparison:

> The best vintages changed hands for **thousands upon thousands of gold coins**, and the Jeroboam wine merchants were some of the richest men in the kingdom.
>
> [Chapter 1 - King Fred the Fearless](https://theickabog.com/king-fred-the-fearless/)

> Fred was particularly gracious today, and each petition ended with the king handing out **a couple of gold coins**, or blessing a baby, or allowing an old woman to kiss his hand.
>
> [Chapter 8 - The Day of Petition](https://theickabog.com/the-day-of-petition/)

> ‘Ah,’ said King Fred, fumbling with the money purse at his belt. ‘Then, good shepherd, **take these few gold coins** and buy yourself a new—’
>
> [Chapter 9 - The Shepherd's Story](https://theickabog.com/the-shepherds-story/)

> Dear little Nobby, in whose memory the king will **add a fat bag of gold** to everybody’s pay this week.
>
> [Chapter 17 - Goodfellow Makes a Stand](https://theickabog.com/goodfellow-makes-a-stand/)

> Scrumble would do anything for gold, and had agreed to impersonate both the widow and the professor for **a hundred ducats**.
>
> [Chapter 21 - Professor Fraudysham](https://theickabog.com/professor-fraudysham/)

> ‘...We estimate the cost of such a brigade, including uniforms, weapons, horses, wages, training, board, lodging, sick pay, danger money, birthday presents, and medals to be around **ten thousand gold ducats**.’
> ‘**Ten thousand ducats**?’ repeated King Fred. ‘**That's a lot it gold**...’
>
> [Chapter 21 - Professor Fraudysham](https://theickabog.com/professor-fraudysham/)

> ‘**Ten thousand ducats a month is a small price to pay**,’ finished Spittleworth
>
> [Chapter 21 - Professor Fraudysham](https://theickabog.com/professor-fraudysham/)

> ‘...I suggest we impose an Ickabog tax. We'll ask every household in Cornucopia to pay **one gold ducat a month**. Of course, this will mean the recruitment and training of many new tax collectors, but it we **raise the amount to two ducats**, we'll cover the cost of them, too’
>
> [Chapter 21 - Professor Fraudysham](https://theickabog.com/professor-fraudysham/)

> ‘Admirable, Spittleworth!’ said King Fred. ‘What a brain you have! Why, **two ducats a month – people will barely notice the loss**.’
>
> [Chapter 21 - Professor Fraudysham](https://theickabog.com/professor-fraudysham/)

> And so **a monthly tax of two gold ducats** was imposed on every household in Cornucopia, to protect the country from the Ickabog.
>
> [Chapter 22 - The House with No Flags](https://theickabog.com/the-house-with-no-flags/)

> ...treason to question the need for the Ickabog tax and treason not to pay your two ducats a month. There was also **a reward of ten ducats** if you reported someone for saying the Ickabog wasn’t real.
>
> [Chapter 22 - The House with No Flags](https://theickabog.com/the-house-with-no-flags/)

> Although he was well paid as carpenter to the king, even Mr Dovetail had **felt the pinch of paying the Ickabog tax**, so he and Daisy had bought fewer pastries than usual, and Mr Dovetail stopped buying wine.
>
> [Chapter 24 - The Bandalore](https://theickabog.com/the-bandalore/)

> ‘Bert, please! Look – I got us Hopes-of-Heaven, I spent **all my pocket money** on them!’
>
> [Chapter 24 - The Bandalore](https://theickabog.com/the-bandalore/)

> Cornucopia was growing slowly poorer. The **rich merchants had no problem paying their Ickabog taxes**. They gave the collectors two ducats a month, then increased the prices on their pastries, cheeses, hams, and wines to pay themselves back. However, **two gold ducats a month was increasingly hard to find** for the poorer folk, especially with food at the markets more expensive. Meanwhile, up in the Marshlands, children began to grow hollow-cheeked.
>
> [Chapter 25 - Lord Spittleworth's Problem](https://theickabog.com/lord-spittleworths-problem/)

> ‘You happen to hear a lot of things, don’t you, Cankerby?’ commented Spittleworth, feeling in his waistcoat for some gold. ‘Very well. **Here are ten ducats for you**.’ ‘Thank you very much, my lord,’ said the footman, bowing low.
>
> [Chapter 25 - Lord Spittleworth's Problem](https://theickabog.com/lord-spittleworths-problem/)

> Everyone called this old woman Ma Grunter. She took in orphans, and was paid **one ducat a month** for each child she had living with her. [...] She didn’t care what a child’s story was; all she cared about was the one ducat a month the authorities paid her for keeping them.
> Chapter 27

> ‘**Five ducat placement fee**,’ – which was what she always asked for, if she could tell somebody really wanted to get rid of a child. Prodd scowled, handed over five ducats, and left without another word.
>
> [Chapter 27 - Kidnapped](https://theickabog.com/kidnapped/)

> ‘Lady Eslanda told me that people are complaining that **the Ickabog tax is too high**. She says rumours are flying that there aren’t even any troops stationed in the north!’ ‘Piffle and poppycock,’ said Spittleworth
>
> [Chapter 33 - King Fred is Worried](https://theickabog.com/king-fred-is-worried/)

> ‘Why don’t we **triple the Ickabog tax**, sire?’ asked Spittleworth, thinking that this would serve the complainers right.
>
> [Chapter 33 - King Fred is Worried](https://theickabog.com/king-fred-is-worried/)

> ‘There will be **fifty ducats for each of you**, if you succeed in this job,’ he said, and the soldiers looked excited. ‘[...] If she escapes, or if you are seen, I shall deny that I gave you this order, **and put you to death**.’
>
> [Chapter 34 - Three More Feet](https://theickabog.com/three-more-feet/)

> After **giving each of Eslanda’s kidnappers fifty ducats**, and reminding them that if they talked, he’d have them executed, Spittleworth smoothed his thin moustaches in a mirror, then went to find Lady Eslanda, who was sitting in his rather dusty library, reading a book by candlelight.
>
> [Chapter 34 - Three More Feet](https://theickabog.com/three-more-feet/)

> A year passed… then two… then three, four, and five. [...] Up in the northern cities, though, people were struggling. More and more businesses – shops, taverns, blacksmiths, wheelwrights, farms, and vineyards – were closing down. **The Ickabog tax was pushing people into poverty**...
>
> [Chapter 36 - Cornucopia Hungry](https://theickabog.com/cornucopia-hungry/)

> However, the effort of **paying the Ickabog tax was too much for the Hopkins family**. They lost their little grocery store, and Hetty’s parents couldn’t help them, because shortly after losing their vineyard, they’d starved to death. Homeless now, their children crying with hunger, Hetty and her husband walked in desperation to Ma Grunter’s orphanage.
>
> [Chapter 36 - Cornucopia Hungry](https://theickabog.com/cornucopia-hungry/)

Comment: Considering the author's well-documented struggles with math, and the absolutely insane currency conversion in Harry Potter, I doubt there's actually an authoritative or reasonable answer to this question.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Whaaaaaat???? Harry Potter makes no economical sense?? </sarcasm>

Comment: The poor people of real-life Europe, of almost any era, could not have supported a monthly tax of even one gold ducat per month, even if the ducat were a very small coin. Cornucopia is rich indeed.